# Codepen - react child components not rendering

Tags: reactjs, codepen

I have a React interview using codepen. I can't get my child elements to show up.

```
class Application extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <div>
     hello
     <Jack />
    </div>
  }
}

class Jack extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        Goodbye
      </div>
    )
  }
}

React.render(<Application />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

In this code, I only see Hello, not Goodbye. The "Jack" component is not being rendered. What can I do?

Comment: can you provide a link for a working codepen ?one more thing, You need to wrap the return of your class inside () since you're returning multiple lines

Comment: Not strictly true about the `()`, it will work regardless.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`React.render(<Application />, document.getElementById('app'));`

should be:

`ReactDOM.render(<Application />, document.getElementById('app'));`

Working example [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-cd8zyb).

Comment: I think that is just a typo as OP says `I only see Hello, not Goodbye.The "Jack" component is not being rendered.`

Comment: Maybe, though I can't see any way that could be the case unless it's something to do with `<Jack />` not being hoisted, because it works fine for me.